# Converting KeyPress Event from VB6 to VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vb6

I need to convert this language (written in VB6) to VB.NET:

```
Private Sub txt1_KeyPress(KeyAscii as Integer)
   If KeyAscii=13 Then
       XXX=CStr(txt1.Text)
       txt2.SetFocus
   End If
End Sub
```

I just wanted that by pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key (KeyAscii=13) the txt1 sets the Focus to the next text box `txt2`.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: You will need to rewire the VB6 app in ASP.Net and keypress events you will have to do in Javascript. Many companies opt to make their VB6 apps run on IE via ActiveX temporarily. If you need to get something to market quick while you rewrite then this could be something you can offer for web customers in the mean time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Txt1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Txt1.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar.ToString = ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then
        Txt2.Focus()
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It gives me error @antagony .
Maybe 'cause I'm using Visual Web Developer?!

Comment: @achab Yes indeed, you **are** going to have trouble converting a VB6 desktop program to a VB.Net web application. Especially any event handling in the GUI.

Comment: So what you think do I need to do for converting it? (Or let the program do the same)?

Comment: You need to write javascript.

Comment: @HansPassant I would like to use it but it's too difficult for me :D

Comment: @achab JavaScript is well worth learning. Or you could try Silverlight, again might require learning. The first job is to decide how important the interactive GUI is. Can you just drop this "tab by entering" behaviour?

Comment: @MarkJ I think i could do that, of course. I'm trying to realize a web-form where you can insert datas (for example: Name, Surname and Email) and store them in a Database in your computer. Not sure if I can do that, of course.. just trying!

Comment: @Achab I assumed your question related to a Winform as there was no indication it was a web application. You really ought to have mentioned that in the question and tagged it with asp.net – although I see someone has added that tag for you now. Anyway, as others have said, you need to either write JavaScript to handle keyboard events or leave that feature out.

Comment: @antagony Thank you for your comment. I'm a bit newbie in programming, sorry for that.